# How can I unwrap a string in Swift to fix error?

Tags: swift

I am trying to make an app that the user selects an option from a tableview cell but I get the error:

> Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'

I get the error on the 5th line and line 16, both about "unwrapping an optional type".

I've tried adding a `!` and searching on the Internet, but I couldn't find any information that could help me fix the error.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DataTableViewCell
    cell?.img.image = UIImage(named: arr[indexPath.row]["name"!])
    cell?.lbl.text = arr[indexPath.row]["name"]
    cell?.lbl2.text = arr[indexPath.row]["subject"]
    cell?.lbl3.text = arr[indexPath.row]["grade"]
    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController
    vc?.str = arr[indexPath.row]["name"]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)

}
```

I expect the program to run without errors.

Comment: Please read [Swift Language Guide, The Basics - Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330)

Comment: let name = are[indexPath.row][name] ?? "Jon"

Answer (score 0):

From [Swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)

> Swift also introduces optional types, which handle the absence of a value. Optionals say either “there is a value, and it equals x” or “there isn’t a value at all”.

How to fix, you have to learn [Optional Chaining.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html)
What you have done is called forced unwrapping.

I think you will get all of your answers here.